# Instability while NDSolving a wave equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to use `NDSolve` to solve a wave equations to check if it is easier and/or faster to use it instead of my old characteristics eq. method implementation.

I'm getting a lot of instability that I don't get with the characteristics method, and since these are simple equations, I wonder what is wrong... (hopefully, not the physical aspect of the problem...)

```
ans = Flatten@NDSolve[{
u[t, x]*D[d[t, x], x] + d[t, x]*D[u[t, x], x] + D[d[t, x], t] == 0,
D[d[t, x], x] + u[t, x]/9.8*D[u[t, x], x] + 
 1/9.8*D[u[t, x], t] + 0.0001 u[t, x]*Abs[u[t, x]] == 0,
u[0, x] == 0,
d[0, x] == 3 + x/1000*1,
u[t, 0] == 0,
u[t, 1000] == 0
},
d, {t, 0, 1000}, {x, 0, 1000}, DependentVariables -> {u, d}
]

Animate[Plot[(d /. ans)[t, x], {x, 0, 1000}, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 6}}], {t, 0, 1000}
]
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**

I've placed the `NDSolve` solution (following JxB's editing) with my characteristics solution, together on the same animation. They match close enough, with the exception of the initial quick oscillations. With time they tend do start do desynchronize, but I believe this is probably due to a small simplification we have to admit when deducing the characteristics.

[image: simulation]

Red: `NDsolve`; Blue: "manual" characteristics method;

press F5 (refresh your browser), to restart the animation from `t=0`.

(xx scale is the number of points I used with my "manual" method, where each point represents 20 units of the `NDSolve`/physical scale)

Playing with `NDSolve` grid sampling, renders completely different oscillation effects. Does anyone have or know of a technique to ensure a proper integration?

Comment: I think you'd get more answers asking in the Math site: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dario Thank you for the suggestion (I'll give it a try). But since these equations should be stable, I thought this was more of a Mathematica issue, although I'm no expert in the matter...

Comment: If you suspect that, since I never used Mathematica, all I can suggest is updating it to the latest version. That might fix your issue if it's caused by a bug in Mathematica

Comment: Are you getting any messages, or just noticing that the `InterpolatingFunction` is misbehaving relative to you solution via characteristics?

Comment: @dario - read "Mathematica issue" as "MathematiCA related issue", as opposed to "MathematiCS related issue" -> that is, not necessarily a bug...

Comment: @rcollyer - yes, but depends a lot on the values I enter, or if I force a min number of grid. This specific example I've posted, I get "At t == 942.8913125190098`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected", and also "Warning: Scaled local spatial error estimate of...". But even when I don't get a message, it is oscillating too much (looking at the animation, it should just do 3 or 4 visual "balances", and then stop). I think the messages come from the incredible osculation, and not "the other way around"

Comment: I'd start by looking at the extended tutorial on [numerical differential equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html), and seeing if that sparks any ideas.  My initial attempts have been failing as much as yours have.

Answer (score 4):

By changing your coefficients to infinite precision (e.g., 1/9.8->10/98), and setting `WorkingPrecision->5` (a value of 6 is too high), I no longer get the error message:

```
ans = Flatten@
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x] d[t, x], x] + D[d[t, x], t] == 0, 
    D[d[t, x], x] + u[t, x] 10/98*D[u[t, x], x] + 
      10/98*D[u[t, x], t] + 1/10000 u[t, x]*Abs[u[t, x]] == 0, 
    u[0, x] == 0, d[0, x] == 3 + x/1000, u[t, 0] == 0, 
    u[t, 1000] == 0}, d, {t, 0, 1000}, {x, 0, 1000}, 
   DependentVariables -> {u, d}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]

Animate[
 Plot[(d /. ans)[t, x], {x, 0, 1000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 6}}], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

I'm don't know this equation, so I don't believe the solution: small-scale oscillations grow initially, then are damped out.

Comment: It is doing much better, and to some point I believe this proves that the high oscillatory effect is some kind of numerical anomaly of the NDSolve. This should be a water wave. The boundary conditions were set to simulate water inside a closed "pool", bouncing between the walls, after water has been dropped from a non horizontal state. So, I also don't believe in the small scale oscillations... also because my "manual" characteristics method don't show this behavior (they just show the long slow wave). If you add the Filling -> Bottom, it becomes more clear what is simulated...

Comment: @JxB It would be good if you would explain why WorkingPrecision should be low (and why 6 is too high).